# No printer in GIMP 2.10 print dialog in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: printing, 18.10, gimp

GIMP print dialog screen:
[image: GIMP print dialog screen]

Printer installed in system:
[image: Devices - Printers]

In the same time TextEditor and Firefox dialogs looks fine:
[image: TextEditor : gedit - print dialog] 
[image: Firefox - print dialog]

How to fix?

Comment: Do you use the SNAP-Version of Gimp? If so, you have to add CUPS-Support to the SNAP-package using "sudo snap connect gimp:cups-control"

Comment: Yep, Snap. "sudo snap connect gimp:cups-control" - fix this. Will be better to write Your comment like answer.

Comment: thx for the feedback - answer is created ;-) best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you're using the SNAP-Version of Gimp.
If so, you have to add CUPS-support to the SNAP-package.

```
sudo snap connect gimp:cups-control
```

Comment: The command works for SNAP installed GIMP 2.10.28 on Ubuntu 20.04 too.

Comment: The command should work for all Ubuntu versions supporting SNAP and all Gimp-Versions installed via SNAP. The command only provides printer-support (cups) to the package. The command is independent of the version.